# Conditionally disabled checkboxes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, rxjs, react-hooks

I am building out a listing of checkboxes and only want the user to be able to select 2 checkboxes and then it will disable the checkboxes. I have a disabled prop which I can pass a boolean but having trouble with the logic to disable the checkbox. I found this solution:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: {} };

  onSelectedChange = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      checked: {
        ...previousState.checked,
        [index]: !previousState.checked[index]
      }
    }));
  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const checkedCount = Object.keys(checked).filter(key => checked[key]).length;
    const disabled = checkedCount > 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index] || false}
            disabled={!checked[index] && disabled}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));


But my javascript syntax knowledge is not great and I cannot understand how this works:


  onSelectedChange = index => {
    this.setState(previousState => ({
      checked: {
        ...previousState.checked,
        [index]: !previousState.checked[index]
      }
    }));
  };


Could someone rewrite it as a function in a react hook and not a component? I would be very grateful, it's 4am and I tried everything lol
```

Answer (score 0):

Base on your function here:

```
onSelectedChange = index => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    checked: {
      ...previousState.checked,
      [index]: !previousState.checked[index]
    }
  }));
};
```

I can image the state will be looking something like

```
{
  checked: {
    1: true,
    2: false,
    //...
  }
}
```

Then you can derived the disable state as

```
// may have better functions which can break early instead of dong an O(n) scan
const disable = Object.values(this.state.checked).filter(elem => elem).length > 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class App extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
  super(props);
  this.state = { checked: {} ,checkCount:0 };
}
  onSelectedChange(index){
   //Create a copy of the state to edit with impunity
    checkedOld = this.state.checked.slice();
    checkedOld[index] = !checkedOld[index];
    //Apply all changes in one statement
    this.setState({checked:checkedOld, checkCount:(this.state.checkCount+1)});

  }
};

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state.checked;
    const disabled = this.state.checkCount> 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index] || false}
            disabled={!checked[index] && disabled}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Give this a go.
What is happening is the React parent object stores both a count of checks and an array of what is checked.
When it calls render, it passes each checkbox both what checkboxes are checked, and a function that will update the **parents** list of checkboxes. In this way, all individual checkbox components can still use a central source of information (The parent's 'state')

Answer (score 0):

as Matthew said, your state looks something like this:

```js
{
  checked: {
    1: true,
    2: false,
    //...
  }
}
```

if you are certain that checkboxes have a limited count like 5, you can have an array of 5 boolean elements indicating each index status.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: Array(5).fill(false) };

  onSelectedChange = (index) => {
    if (index < 0 || index > 4) return;
    const checked = [...this.state.checked];
    checked[index] = !checked[index];

    this.setState(() => ({ checked }));
  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const checkedCount = checked.filter((c) => c === true).length;
    const disabled = checkedCount > 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => (
          <input
            key={index}
            onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
            type="checkbox"
            checked={checked[index]}
            disabled={!checked[index] && disabled}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

A better way would be to have an array of checked indexes.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = { checked: [] };

  onSelectedChange = (index) => {
    const checkedIndex = this.state.checked.findIndex(e => e === index);
    const checked = [...this.state.checked];
    if (checkedIndex > 0) {
      checked.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      checked.push(index);
    }
    this.setState((previousState) => ({ checked }));
  };

  render() {
    const { checked } = this.state;
    const disabled = checked.length > 1;

    return (
      <div>
        {Array.from({ length: 5 }, (_element, index) => {
          const isChekced = checked.includes(index);
          return (
            <input
              key={index}
              onChange={() => this.onSelectedChange(index)}
              type="checkbox"
              checked={isChekced}
              disabled={!isChekced && disabled}
            />
          )
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Please note that `checked={checked[index] || false}` equels to `checked={checked[index]}`.
Also according to [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor):

> Constructor is the only place where you should assign this.state
> directly.

So it is better to initialize local state in the constructor.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      // Don't call this.setState() here!
      this.state = {  checked: [] };
      this.onSelectedChange = this.onSelectedChange.bind(this);
    }
    // ...
}
```